# Why did Madara’s second eye exist at all?

Tags: naruto

He used Izanagi to survive losing his battle with Hashirama and swiping his DNA, shouldn’t his other eye be permanently sealed?

[image]

Comment: Not sure but I think it was the awakening of the rinnegan that healed his eye. his eye was not a sharingan anymore so it did not have the characteristics of a sharingan so the izanagi would not effect the vision.

Comment: i just want to conform that, is that madara's eyes. It looks like itachi's eye to me. And how the madara's eye in which part of anime or manga you felt that madara's eye should have been sealed.

Comment: I can't understand your question. Madara used Izanagi to undo his death and on doing, he loses his right eye. [and that is Itachi's eye in the pic FYI]